# Error message using plm in R: Variable length differ

Tags: r, dataset, panel-data, plm

I have a problem using the plm-package in R:

assuming that data1 is my dataset, I treid to estimate  pooled OLS model:

```
plm(demand ~ storage + ABB ,data=data1, model="pooling", index = c("country","month"))
```

but I receive the error message:

```
> plm(demand ~ storage + ABB ,data=data1, model="pooling", index = c("country","month"))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X')
```

Here  is some information about my dataset:

```
> summary(data1)
      country             month           demand                   storage                      ABB       
 Australia:  362   01.01.1984:   47   0,75   :   47   0,100000000000009:    4   101052266666667,00:    2  
 Austria  :  362   01.01.1985:   47   2,17   :   32   1,2              :    3   10308680,00       :    2  
 Belgium  :  362   01.01.1986:   47   1,25   :   26   10,8             :    3   10332560,00       :    2  
 Brazil   :  362   01.01.1987:   47   0,83   :   24   19,8             :    3   10335710,00       :    2  
 Canada   :  362   01.01.1988:   47   3,25   :   17   464,4            :    3   10336160,00       :    2  
 Chile    :  362   01.01.1989:   47   (Other):11393   (Other)          : 6097   (Other)           :15544  
 (Other)  :14816   (Other)   :16706   NA's   : 5449   NA's             :10875   NA's              : 1434  
> class(data1)
[1] "data.frame"
> str(data1)
'data.frame':   16988 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ country: Factor w/ 47 levels "Australia","Austria",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ month  : Factor w/ 362 levels "01.01.1984","01.01.1985",..: 1 32 63 93 123 153 183 213 243 273 ...
 $ demand : Factor w/ 8907 levels "-0,25","-85,17",..: 8198 8639 8870 8639 463 605 898 807 599 302 ...
     $ storage: Factor w/ 6041 levels "0,0274661240604858",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ABB    : Factor w/ 15541 levels "100.054.416.666.667",..: 4192 4200 4210 4221 4232 4244 4257 4272 4278 4283 ...
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: converting all regression variables with as.numeric() solves my problem. the plm()-command is now working. Thank you!

Comment: Please be very careful about your data though: check up on *n* (number of records) in the output to make sure your regression set is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable *demand* seems to be a factor. Since you're using `plm` I assume you want that as a numeric.  You can use `as.numeric` to convert this.